# JFace TreeViewer inputChanged

Tags: eclipse-plugin, treeview, editor, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using JFace `TreeViewer` in order to list some data in a tree structure. I am using multiple diffirent root for editor and i change the tree viewer's input via an editor. How can I set the new root in `inputChanged` method within the content provider class?

```java
@Override
public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
    this._viewer = (TreeViewer) viewer;
    /* Register Listeners if Input is available */
    if (newInput != null && oldInput == null) {

    }

    /* If new Input is NULL, unregister Listeners */
    else if (newInput == null && oldInput != null) {            
}
```

More specifically how can I listen to changes in my editor page?

Comment: You don't change the input in `inputChanged` - you call `setInput` on the viewer and the viewer will call `inputChanged` again.

Comment: Yes indeed but my problem is, i am changing the root on the run time. Passing parameter from the editor, listing that data related to that parameter. I want treeviewer to uptade the root by itself when it is running. In this case if change the input, it gives an ClassCastException since the data models belong to the different classes. @greg-449

Comment: Create one marker interface and make all root to implement that interface and on run time add different root model.